# pass values from jsp to servlet using hrefff

Tags: jsp, servlets

Hi I have problem in my code.
In JSP page

```
<a href="readnews?id=${n.id}">Read more</a>
```

In server

```
String id = request.getParameter("id");    
try {
    News detailnews = DAO.getDetailsNews(id);
    request.setAttribute("news", detailnews);        
} catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(readnews.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

but `id = null` when I run
Help me please!!!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change it to `id=${news.id}`.